# Getting a redux-oidc JavaScript error when I try to navigate to sign in, where would I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, identityserver4, openid-connect, redux-oidc

I tried implementing redux-oidc by following the guide on the GitHub page. I am connecting to a IDP server built by me using identity server. I thought everything was set up properly but got the error below. How can I fix this or find the source of the issue?

[image: Error when clicking sign in button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, the issue was happening because I needed to add Prevent Default to the button click.